# Capybara Finding Button but Not Submitting Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm writing a feature test on a user signup form and using Capybara with rspec to test it. Capybara is successfully finding the button, but the test results come back and show that the text it's finding on the page is from the page the form is on, not the page that loads after. I can't seem to find out why the form isn't submitting via the test, I've tried several ways of clicking on the button and each time it finds the button but it doesn't trigger the form to be sent.

Capybara Test Failure Error

```
Failures:

  1) submitting a new user creates a new user
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("Traid with harold_houdini!")
       expected to find text "Traid with harold_houdini!" in "Sign In Sign in with Google Sign In Sign in with Google First name: Last name: Birthday: Gender: Female Male Username: You can change your username whenever you'd like. Email: Password: Password confirmation: Address: Secondary address: City: State: Zip code: Country: What do you have to offer? What are you looking for?"
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/given_core-3.8.0/lib/given/rspec/monkey.rb:21:in `handle_matcher'
     # ./spec/features/users/new_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.03 seconds (files took 3.33 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/users/new_spec.rb:5 # submitting a new user creates a new user
```

Capybara Test

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'rails_helper'

describe "submitting a new user" do
    it "creates a new user" do
        visit '/users/new'
        within ("#new_user") do
            fill_in "user[first_name]", with: "Harold"
            fill_in "user[last_name]", with: "Houdini"
            fill_in "user[username]", with: "harold_houdini"
            fill_in "user[email]", with: "harold_houdini@gmail.com"
            fill_in "user[password]", with: "password"
            fill_in "user[password_confirmation]", with: "password_confirmation"
        end
        page.find("#new-user-form").click
        expect(page).to have_content("Traid with harold_houdini!")
    end
end
```

Rails Helper

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  # config.include Capybara::DSL
  # Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5


  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

end
```

User Form Partial (Rendered)

```
<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="8CLe05BTkyXtB0f7HKRjqfcRhFNSdbrxg7DQeBLvxCNzLeCpPWyeK82V4VnIUjJfSvgmjYGiTCYLGtriDZV9kA==">

   ...........

    <div>
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="submit" id="new-user-form">
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Please show the actual HTML of the form rather than the erb.  Also is there a reason you're using `find(...).click` rather than `click_button('new_user_form')` ???

Comment: I updated the main post to show the beginning and end of the form HTML instead of erb. Regarding the find(...).click, I had variations of click_button before and none of them worked. The find(...).click was just the latest attempt I had done when I copied to SO.  I have also tried click_button("commit"), click_button("submit"), click_button("new-user-form"), click_button("#new-user-form") and none of them worked @ThomasWalpole

Comment: Are you setting variables for password and password_confirmation? If not, these two fields should match.

Comment: I think @hashrocket has nailed it here -- If password and password-confirmation are set to different things the form submission is going to fail, check your `test.log` to see what's actually being submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hashrocket was able to catch the error, I simply did not have my correct password/password combination combo. After updating, I changed my button clicker to click_button("new-user-form") which located the button by id and successfully submitted.